# android developer console issue

Tags: android

Yesterday my android app's active install was 76% and today it is 80% even though the number of install has not changed at all. Is it possible to go upward without increasing the number of installs? I guess this is a bug in Google's android developer console. Anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps people who had uninstalled the app previously re-installed it.  This would increase the number of active installs but not increase the number of unique downloads.

Comment: oh I didn't know that the number does not increases if the same user installs again.